# How do I enable my wireless switch? HP Pavilion dv4000

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I found some information to run a test and discovered that my Pro Wireless (Intel)
has been disabled.  There seems to be information on how to check things but I cannot 
find out how to ENABLE it or TURN IT ON.

THIS WAS ALL WORKING FINE UNTIL THE OTHER DAY AND POOF... DISABLED
But I cannot find hardware or software by that name.  AND...
No where can I find information on how to find the switch and Enable it OR turn it on.

So how do I enable my wireless switch on my HP Pavilion dv4000

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/56045/wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch

Answer (score 1):

The wireless On/Off switch is on the top panel.  See image below.

[image]