# Ubuntu 12.10 wireless adapter problem

Tags: wireless, 12.10

Any one know how to hard unlock wireless adapter in Ubuntu 12.10

I have Toshiba Satellite laptop c640 with dual boot. The wireless adapter works fine in windows . But in Ubuntu it shows "disabled by hardware".

I tried `rfkill unblock all` . Then nothing happened to the lock.

I checked "lspci | grep wireless " it shows the wireless device .

Comment: Can you run `lspci | grep wireless` and `lsusb` and edit your question to include the output?

Answer (score 2):

Check to find either the switch is turned "off" or blocked in the BIOS if not run `sudo rfkill unblock all`and `sudo rfkill list` to see what is blocking the wireless

Some have a hotkey like Fn+F2 (or something else) that will turn it on or off.

[Wireless is disabled by hardware switch](https://askubuntu.com/q/56045/46312)

Comment: I checked the BIOS , there is no settings for wireless enabling,and in my lap there is no physical switch for wireless adapter .

Comment: did it work with the Live CD/DVD

Comment: Green  Not working

Answer (score 1):

I made the wireless adapter working in ubuntu . Login to the windows 7 (My other boot os), Then Disable and Enable the wireless adapter using "fn+f8" then boot into ubuntu then it works .I think the ubuntu driver for wireless has some drawbacks .

Regards
Sachindranath